# Uninstall FTP Sync from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there an easy way to uninstall the FTP-Sync package I have installed in VSC? There doesn't seem to be a remove feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see all installed extensions and uninstall them using these steps:

1. `Ctrl+P`(Quick Open).
2. Enter `>Extensions: Show Installed Extensions`.
3. Click the "x" icon next to the extension you want to uninstall.

Here is how is looks:

[image]